# How to parse list of integers when sending csv file from logstash to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to load a csv file from logstash into elasticseach. One of the fields is a list of integers that is represented as the following snippet of my data shows :

`transaction_date,customer_name,age,job,fidelity_card_id,product_id_sold,
2/24/2017;14:15:43,Roberto Michel,25,Analyst Programmer,4.17500359418653E+015,"431, 1032, 197, 684, 201, 206, 1022, 922, 556, 677","4, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 10, 67, 1"`

I want precise in the configuration file that am creating in logstash that the two last fields are lists of integers but I did not figured out how to proceed.

if I do nothing the elasticsearch mapp both of the last two fields as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at the [split](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-filters-split.html) or [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split) filters (the latter one might be easier to use)

Comment: thank you for your reply i tryed mutate with split but nothing chaged the field is still with a string type i want it to be parsed as an integer (an array of integers)

Comment: the mutate filter also supports  a convert function, have you tried that? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert

Comment: under the filter plugin i added these settings mutate  {
convert =>{"age"  => "integer"     }
split => { "quantity" => "," }
split => { "product_id_sold" => ","}
convert => {"product_id_sold"=> "integer"}
}
}
but with convert the field only takes the first value of the array  as integer  and does  not contain anymore other values such as "product_id_sold": 723,